# ios7 textfield shouldchangecharactersinrange is not called when a word is selected from autocorrection bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uikeyboard

`UITextField` `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` `delegate` method is not called when a word is selected from autocorrection bar with simplified Chinese keyboard. When I type 'ni hao', this `delegate` method gets called for each character, but when I selected a word from autocorrect suggestion bar this delegate method is not called. This is only happening in `iOS 7` with simplified chinese, it is working fine with japanese keyboard. I want to do my application specific action when selecting the word. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I meet the same issue today.  I fixed it as below:

Don't use delegate, just use Notification:

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(textChanged:)
                                                 name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];

Comment: I tried this, but its not worked for me,What you implemented in textChanged event.? please tell me more about your implementation it will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue, too. Thanks to @AnkyHe 's solution. Here is my implemention.

In the ViewController which hold your UITextField:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(textChanged:)
                                                 name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)textChanged:(NSNotification *)notif
{
    UITextField *editingTextField = (UITextField *)notif.object;
    NsLog(@"changed textL %@", editingTextField.text);
}
```

Comment: Make sure you call `removeObserver` in the `dealloc` method of the view controller.